Running unit tests results in error message "Target class [config] does not exist"
Some unit tests need some preparation. To not write the same code over and over, I created a test base class, e.g.
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

// ...

class ActingAsTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, WithFaker, CreatesApplication;

    // ...


    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        // ...
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        // ...

        parent::tearDown();
    }

}

Now I create my test class:
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\SomeController;

use Tests\ActingAsTestCase;

// ...

class MyUITest extends ActingAsTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}

In one of the unit tests, I use values from config(). But when I run the tests, I get the error message Target class [config] does not exist.?
How to solve the problem?
Edit
Laravel version is: Laravel Framework 9.35.1
I don't think the unit test is the reason. When I set in the phpunit.xml the attribute processIsolation="true", then the tests are running without a failure, but it takes very long.

Can you show where you are calling config()?

Also, which Laravel version are you using?

Are you calling config() inside a test or in a setup or a dataprovider? Please, show the code...
